# Splitting data in pandas series

Tags: python, pandas

I have dataframe which I build with API calls. I am calling the API 120 times and getting 1000x31 dataset which I append each time I call the API.

```
def load_full2(times):
    dfs = []
    item_count = 0
    while item_count <= times:
        response = requests.post(url_2,data=json.dumps(data_two),headers=headers)
        response_json = response.json()
        result = pd.io.json.json_normalize(response_json['hits']['hits'])
        item_count+=1
        dfs.append(result)


    df = pd.concat(dfs, ignore_index=True)
    df.to_csv("export2.csv", encoding='utf-8', index=False)
```

My final dataset which I export looks like this:

120000x31

```
id    _index    _score     _source.agent    _source.cookie                                                                                                                                  .source.id    _source.log    _source.keys    _source.name    _source.category    _source.class    _source.companyid    _source.cname    _source.ip    _source.method    _source.process    _source.skid    _source.severity    _source.sysname    _source.template    _source.time    _source.country    _source.event    _source.hostname    _source.ipip    _source.namespace    _source.refer    _source.request_url    _source.type
n/a    n/a      n/a        n/a              __cfduid=d118f225fac35345d9e1d87e533b596ec1574680126; gclid=EAIaIQobChMIhNSMxZyF5gIVjMjeCh3V2A-pEAAYASABEgJQBPD_BwE; full_path=google.com       n/a           n/a           n/a           n/a           n/a           n/a           n/a           n/a           n/a           n/a           n/a           n/a           n/a           n/a           n/a           n/a           n/a           n/a           n/a           n/a           n/a           n/a           n/a           n/a           n/a           n/a           n/a           n/a       https://google.com/au/?gclid=CjwKCAiAlO7uBRANEiwA_vXQ--5YOAD-mFNQFuM0dbd7lHsRBZSfOvhQynhZMhNHkEX-m7gosL23ABoCyS4QAvD_BwE
```

My main interest are the '_source.cookie' and '_source.request_url' columns. My goal is to have 2 new columns added to my dataset, the first one being `Gclid from cookie` which would hold the value after ***gclid=*** which ends at ***;***. The second column would be `Glid_from_url` which would hold the value from `_service.request_url` either after ***gclid=*** or ***click_id=***

My desired output would look like this:

120000x33

```
id    ...    _source.cookie    ...    _source.request_url   gclid_from_cookie      gclid_from_url 
1     ...    c1574680126; gclid=EAIaIQobChMIhNSMxZyF5gIVjMjeCh3V2A-pEAAYASABEgJQBPD_BwE; full_pat     ...    pn/?gclid=CjwKCAiAlO7uBRANEiwA_vXQ--5YOAD-mFNQFuM0dbd7lHsRBZSfOvhQynhZMhNHkEX-m7gosL23ABoCyS4QAvD_BwE    EAIaIQobChMIhNSMxZyF5gIVjMjeCh3V2A-pEAAYASABEgJQBPD_BwE       CjwKCAiAlO7uBRANEiwA_vXQ-yQeCe4-vuWQiZapqU7H5-YODheBwQf2Ra0c8CZwjf1ZGSqkw1KKXxoCeYMQAvD_BwE
2     ...    c1574680126; gclid=EAIaIQobChMIhNSMxZyF5gIVjMjeCh3V2A-pEAAYASABEgJQBPD_BwE; full_pat     ...    to/?click_type=gclid&click_id=CjwKCAiAlO7uBRANEiwA_vXQ-yQeCe4-vuWQiZapqU7H5-YODheBwQf2Ra0c8CZwjf1ZGSqkw1KKXxoCeYMQAvD_BwE&click_     EAIaIQobChMIhNSMxZyF5gIVjMjeCh3V2A-pEAAYASABEgJQBPD_BwE        CjwKCAiAlO7uBRANEiwA_vXQ-yQeCe4-vuWQiZapqU7H5-YODheBwQf2Ra0c8CZwjf1ZGSqkw1KKXxoCeYMQAvD_BwE
...
```

I am fairly new with programming, not sure how I would move forward and how would I code it. Would I try to split during the building of the file in each while loop splitting the strings from the 2 columns that are in my interest or I would do it after the full file is compiled?

The second problem is that in ***_source.request_url*** column the value is set either under `gclid=` or `click_id=`. So I am not sure how would I split the string when the value could exist in one of those strings or don't exist at all.

When I tried splitting the strings I got an error `AttributeError: 'Series' object has no attribute 'split'`

I really appreciate your help.

Comment: Please edit your dataframe to include all (and only) relevant columns, and align it to improve readability.

Comment: Hi, I have updated the dataframe with all columns, marked n/a for non-applicable columns and added values for columns that interests me.

Answer (score 0):

1. Better to do it after the creation of dataframe.
2. You can't directly use string operations on `pd.Series` you have to convert it to str like this:

   ```
   df['str_col'].str.split(':')
   ```

For example:
Let say you have a dataframe like this:

```
data = {'Name':['Tom:bar', 'nick:bar', 'krish:bar', 'jack:bar'], 'Age':[20, 21, 19, 18]} 

# Create DataFrame 
df = pd.DataFrame(data) 
print(df)
[Out]:
        Name   Age
0    Tom:bar   20
1   nick:bar   21
2  krish:bar   19
3   jack:bar   18
```

You can create a new col with such operation:

```
df['bar_col'] = [x.split(':')[1] for x in df.Name]
print(df)
[Out]:
        Name  Age  bar_col
0    Tom:bar   20  bar
1   nick:bar   21  bar
2  krish:bar   19  bar
3   jack:bar   18  bar
```

Comment: It's more of a guiding comment than an answer to his questions.

Comment: @Aryerez what about now? I was trying to guide him rather handover the answer.

Answer (score 0):

The dataframe is still a little bit difficult to read, but using the following example:

```py
df = pd.DataFrame({'_source.request_url': ['https://google.com/au/?gclid=CjwKCAiAlO7uBRANEiwA_vXQ--5YOAD-mFNQFuM0dbd7lHsRBZSfOvhQynhZMhNHkEX-m7gosL23ABoCyS4QAvD_BwE', 'https://google.com/au/?click_id=CjwKCAiAlO7uBRANEiwA_vXQ--5YOAD-mFNQFuM0dbd7lHsRBZSfOvhQynhZMhNHkEX-m7gosL23ABoCyS4QAvD_BwE', 'no match example'], 
                   '_source.cookie': ['__cfduid=d118f225fac35345d9e1d87e533b596ec1574680126; gclid=EAIaIQobChMIhNSMxZyF5gIVjMjeCh3V2A-pEAAYASABEgJQBPD_BwE;', '__cfduid=d118f225fac35345d9e1d87e533b596ec1574680126; gclid=EAIaIQobChMIhNSMxZyF5gIVjMjeCh3V2A-pEAAYASABEgJQBPD_BwE;', None]})
```

To extract the string between = and ;, you can use the regex pattern `r'=(.+?);'`.

```py
import re

def get_glid_from_source(pattern, data):

    result = re.search(pattern, str(data))
    if result is not None:
        return result.group(1)
    return None

df['glid_from_url'] = df.apply(lambda x: get_glid_from_source('[gclid|click_id]=(.+?)$', x['_source.request_url']), axis=1)
df['gclid_from_cookie'] = df.apply(lambda x: get_glid_from_source('gclid=(.+?)[;%&]', x['_source.cookie']), axis=1)
```

If there are no matches in the data, the regex will return None, so you have to catch it with `if result is not None`.

The output dataframe is:

```
    _source.request_url _source.cookie                  glid_from_url                                                                                           gclid_from_cookie
0   https://google.com/au/?gclid=CjwKCAiAlO7uBRANE...   __cfduid=d118f225fac35345d9e1d87e533b596ec1574...   CjwKCAiAlO7uBRANEiwA_vXQ--5YOAD-mFNQFuM0dbd7lH...   EAIaIQobChMIhNSMxZyF5gIVjMjeCh3V2A-pEAAYASABEg...
1   https://google.com/au/?click_id=CjwKCAiAlO7uBR...   __cfduid=d118f225fac35345d9e1d87e533b596ec1574...   CjwKCAiAlO7uBRANEiwA_vXQ--5YOAD-mFNQFuM0dbd7lH...   EAIaIQobChMIhNSMxZyF5gIVjMjeCh3V2A-pEAAYASABEg...
2   no match example                                    None                                                None                                                None
```

This example works if there is only ever one match in the data, if there are multiple matches and you want to catch that then use `re.findall(pattern, data)`.

Comment: I get an error ```df['glid_from_url'] = df['_source.request_url'].apply(lambda x: re.search('[gclid|click_id]=(.+?);', s).group(1))
NameError: name 's' is not defined```

Comment: Hi, thank you for your edit, having the error: ```df['glid_from_url'] = df['_source.request_url'].apply(lambda x: re.search('[gclid|click_id]=(.+?)$', x).group(1))
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'group'``` I think the code does not apply if the entry is empty, right?

Comment: Hi again Merelda, regex expression works for the second one flawlessly, but for the first one there are errors because the string does not always end with `;`, it ends with `&`, or `%`, how could I add possible endings?

Comment: You should probably look into [`regex`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html). Use `[]` to indicate a set of characters to be matched. So the pattern to have a string end with `%`, `&` and `;` would be `gclid=(.+?)[;%&]`